# Duplicate % register and pass as an argument

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I use the `%` register to compile the current `.tex` file using `pdflatex`. I have this mapped to `ww`, where the file is first saved and then compiled.

```
map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex % <CR>
```

This works fine. Now I tried copying `%` to another register and then create similar mapping using the new register, but that doesn't work.

```
let @a=@%
map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex a <CR>
```

When I compile, I get the following error message:

```
! I can't find file `a'.
<*> a
```

However, when I check the register `a` using `echo @a`, the register has been created correctly. So I don't understand why this doesn't work. Please help.

P.S. My ultimate goal is to create a conditional mapping:

```
if % contains 'chapter':
    map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex ../main.tex <CR>
else
    map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex % <CR>
```

So that vim can handle the directory structure:

```
.
├── chapter1
│   ├── chapter1.tex
├── chapter2
│   ├── chapter2.tex
├── chapter3
│   ├── chapter3.tex
├── main.tex
```

Comment: Your problem is that `%` is not a register, it's just a placeholder for the current file (despite `"%` being a register holding that value as well). You can insert the value from a register with Ctrl-R plus the letter of that register, so do `map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex <C-R>a <CR>`, where `<C-R>` is a single "letter" created by pressing Ctrl-V, followed by Ctrl-R in insert mode.

Comment: @L3viathan, you shoul consider turning that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is not a register itself, it is an "Ex special character" (see `:h cmdline-special`).

In order to paste the contents of a register in insert or commandline/ex mode, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, followed by the character that identifies the register. If you edit e.g. your `.vimrc` and would do that in insert mode, you'll paste the value that register has *currently*, which is no good for use in a mapping, so you need to escape it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>:

```
map :ww :w <CR> :!pdflatex ^Ra <CR>
```

Here, `^R` is a single character that was created with the key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

---

There might be a second issue I see with your approach, if I understand it correctly:

Your `let @a=@%` is also evaluated on start of your editor, if it's in your `.vimrc`. To fix that, move that and the mapping into an autocommand (`:h autocmd`).

Answer (score 0):

> My ultimate goal is to create a conditional mapping

```
nn <expr>ww ':up <bar> !pdflatex '..(@% =~? 'chapter\d\+\.tex$' ? '%:h:h/main.tex' : '%')..'<CR>'
```